# relational and conditional data coding

Tags: r, dplyr, relational-database

I have a data set with each state listed from 1990 to 2016 (27 observations per state, for 50 states, is 1350 observations). In the data set, I have `state`, `year`, `pass` (passage of some law), and a list of the state's `neighbors`. The data look like this...

```
> head(data)
    state year pass                             neighbors
1 Alabama 1990    0 Mississippi,Tennessee,Georgia,Florida
2 Alabama 1991    0 Mississippi,Tennessee,Georgia,Florida
3 Alabama 1992    0 Mississippi,Tennessee,Georgia,Florida
4 Alabama 1993    0 Mississippi,Tennessee,Georgia,Florida
5 Alabama 1994    0 Mississippi,Tennessee,Georgia,Florida
6 Alabama 1995    0 Mississippi,Tennessee,Georgia,Florida
```

I'm trying to figure out how to do the following:

For example, take the `state` and `year` for row 1 (Alabama in 1990), look through that row’s list of neighbors (each item) and look for that item (state) in the vector of states, in that same year, to see if they passed that law `pass==1`. If so, create a new variable `neighbor_passed` evaluated to `1`.

For instance, it would iterate, looking for Mississippi in 1990 to see if `pass == 1`, then Tennessee in 1990 to see if `pass==1`. It would do this for each row, matching the `year` of that row, to search if `pass==1` for any state in `neighbors` in that same year.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
f<-function(x){
  x[5]<-0
  for(row in 1:dim(x)[1]){
    ego_state <- x[row,1]
    ego_year <- x[row,2]
    alter_list <- x[row,4]
    alter_list <- as.character(unlist(alter_list))
    neighbors <- unlist(strsplit(alter_list, "[,]"))
    for(i in neighbors){
      year <- ego_year
      print(paste(i,year))
      #if(x[1]==i && x[2]==year && x[3]==1){
        #x[5]<-1
      #}
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see in what I've commented out, I want the function to look through the column/variable `states` to find the item in `neighbors` (e.g. Mississippi) in ego's same year (e.g. 1990), go to THAT row (where `state` == Mississippi and `year` == 1990), and check if `pass` == 1. If so, I'd like for another variable to be created (e.g. `neighbor_passed`), where the value of 1 is input. For all others, 0 is input. Then continue through the iteration for all i in `neighbors`, per `year`, and continue the iteration for each row in the data set.

Comment: You say "how to do the following" but then you just give two examples. Examples of what? Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly say how what is returned is a function of the input. See [ask] & [mcve] & show what relevant parts or subproblems you can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go!

```
data$neighbor_passed<-unlist(lapply(1:length(data$state), 
       function(j) {neighbors_j<-unlist(strsplit(as.character(data$neighbors[j]),","));
          sum(unlist(lapply(neighbors_j,function(x) data$pass[data$year==data[j,]$year & data$state==x])))>0}))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly.

```
library(dplyr)
data <- mutate(data, neighbor_passed =
                 ifelse(pass == 0, 0, 1))
```